# Why is there an extra scope in between my parent and child directives?

Tags: javascript, scope, angularjs

I have a directive which then as part of its template uses an inner directive. When a certain thing happens in my inner directive, I want to call a function in the scope of the parent directive. I thought the '&' for the `scope` property on the directive was for this kind of scenario. However, when I try to call the function, the function in the parent directive never gets called. See the jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hdm3Q/

When debugging, I found that `$parent` on the scope of the inner directive was not the same as the scope of the parent directive. It wasn't until I did `scope.$parent.$parent` that I found the scope for the outer directive. So, why is this extra scope here? How can I call the function on my parent scope. I'd really like to have isolated scope in these directives. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name translation between `parentFunction` and `parent-function` is happening.

In your directive, you should use hyphenated version of the name.
This rule applies to all the angular html attributes.

```
<div child parent-function="parentFunction()"></div>
```

working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/p2dtC/